# Lower bound on probability of pairwise intersection of events

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let $A_1,\cdots, A_n$ be $n$ events of some probability space, such that for all $k\in [n]$ we have $\text{Pr}[A_k]=\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon\in (0,1)$.

I'm interested in the following quantity:

$$f(n)=\max_{i\not=j}\text{Pr}[A_i\cap A_j]$$

My question is: what is the minimum of $f(n)$ expressed in terms of $n$ and $\epsilon$ over all possible probability space and events?

In particular, do we have $f(n)\rightarrow \epsilon$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

A naive application of inclusive exclusive principle yields $f(n)\ge \epsilon^2$ for large enough $n$. Can we improve this?

I'm sure this problem must appears somewhere in the literature, but I can't find a keyword to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it shows an explicit example, where $f(n) = \epsilon^2$ for all $n\geq 2$ and thus in general there cannot be a better bound than $\epsilon^2$.

We will consider the probability space $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{P}=Uniform(0,1)$ as our probability measure. We consider $\epsilon = \frac{1}{m}$, where $m\in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$. We define
$$A_n = \bigcup_{k=0}^{m^{n-1}-1}[\frac{k}{m^{n-1}},\frac{k}{m^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{m^n})$$
such that $A_n$ is a union of $m^{n-1}$ disjoint intervals of length $\frac{1}{m^n}$ and thus $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\frac{m^{n-1}}{m^n} = \frac{1}{m}$. For example $A_1 = [0,\frac1m)$, $A_2=[0,\frac{1}{m^2})\cup[\frac{1}{m},\frac1m + \frac{1}{m^2}) \cup \dots \cup [\frac{m-1}{m}, \frac{m-1}{m}+\frac{1}{m^2})$ and so on. If $i<j$, then for each of the $m^{i-1}$ intervals in $A_i$, this interval contains exactly $m^{j-i-1}$ intervals of $A_j$ and since each intersection of intervals will have length $m^{-j}$, the total length of the intersection will be $m^{i-1}m^{j-i-1}m^{-j}=m^{-2}$.
And therefore 
$$\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = \frac{1}{m^2} \quad \text{for all } i\neq j$$